# "Not only ... but also" with a normal verb and an adjective

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms

Is it natural to say

> The pop-up message here does not only carry sufficient information but also is confusing

when I have these two facts:

1. The pop-up message doesn't carry sufficient information
2. What's worse, it is rather confusing

Also, should I insert "rather" somewhere in my sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An earlier answer has already said this, but I think it bears repeating:

> Your current structure does not convey the facts you mention.

The vital thing to understand here is that the words "not only"
do not negate the words that come after them.
When you say or write, "not only X," you affirm that X is true,
and you imply that there are other things that can be said on the same topic.
"Not only X but also Y" is a special way of saying "X and Y."
This phrasing might be used if X is something good and Y is better,
or if (as in this case) X is something bad and Y is worse.
It can also emphasize both X *and* Y.

Since "not only X but Y" means "X and Y", one way to put together your
facts 1 and 2 is,

> **Not only** does the pop-up message not carry sufficient information, **but also** it is confusing.

This now has the correct meaning, but its style can be improved.
First, rather than "not ... sufficient", we can use "insufficient":

> **Not only** does the pop-up message carry insufficient information, **but also** it is confusing.

Because the words "not only" imply that there is more to follow,
the word "also" in "not only ... but also" is redundant:

> **Not only** does the pop-up message carry insufficient information, **but** it is confusing.

This has the disadvantage that the word "but" often conjoins two things that contrast with each other, whereas here we have one thing that is like the other but more stronger. It would be better to omit the word "but", which
is not needed in this particular sentence:

> **Not only** does the pop-up message carry insufficient information, it is confusing.

In this sentence, the comma is sufficient to separate the two facts that
you want to state.
The construction "not only ... but" is an idiom that is useful when
the two elements following "not only" require a word to separate them,
usually because they are not complete statements by themselves:

> The pop-up message is **not only** uninformative **but** confusing.

---

A note on the possible use of the word "rather" in any of these sentences:
"rather" has several possible meanings. From http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rather:

> in ​preference to or as a ​preference
>
> more ​accurately; more ​exactly
>
> to a ​noticeable ​degree; ​somewhat

The second sense often occurs in the construction "not ... but rather".
For example, you might say

> The popup is not an informative message but rather a source of confusion.

If you write

> The popup is rather confusing,

a listener will likely take "rather" in its third sense;
the sentence is understood to mean that the popup is somewhat confusing.
This meaning is likely to be conveyed even if the word "rather"
appears within a sentence where two things are being compared or contrasted.

Answer (score 5):

Your current structure does not convey the facts you mention. In its current state, it is saying that carrying sufficient information is not the only thing it does, when it should say that it *doesn't* carry sufficient information (or carries insufficient information). The wording I would choose is:

> Not only does this pop-up message carry insufficient information, but it is also confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way, using **not only...as well**:

> *Not only* does the popup carry *in*sufficient information, it is
>   confusing *as well*.

P.S. <strike>I see the OP uses inversion, but</strike> for other passersby, note the inversion:  "Not only *does* the popup..."

Comment: You're right. I misremembered. I should have read his question again before tacking a P.S. onto my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to combine these two complete ideas in one sentence using not only.. but also..

> The pop-up message not only carries insufficient information but, worse, it is also rather confusing.

The [not only.. but also..](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also) construction is challenging to use and contributes no more to the meaning than the much simpler **furthermore**. As you want to emphasise the second point, it might be better to omit it:

> The pop-up message carries insufficient information and, worse, it is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: "The pop-up message doesn't carry enough information and is quite confusing."